# C#; EF database first mode

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, db-first

I used database-first mode in EF. I need your help because I have a problem when I try to run this code:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string SNumber = txtSearchByNum.Text;
   
    var qSearchByTypeText = database.tblNote.SqlQuery("select * From tblNote Where fNumber=@t0", SNumber).ToList();
}
```

I get this error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll
>
> Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@t0".

Could this be due to the ٍEntity Framework version?

Comment: Which version of entity framework are you using?

Comment: Why would you use a sql string for something that Entity Framework is capable of doing? `var qSearchByTypeText = database.tblNote.Where(note => note.fNumber == SNumber).ToList();`

Comment: entity framework6.0.0

Comment: This is not a problem with EF. You must declare the scalar variable `"@t0".` in your command.

Comment: please Help me that how declare the scalar variable "@t0"?

Comment: var qSearchByTypeText = database.tblNote.Where(note => note.fNumber == SNumber).ToList();  what do you mean (note => note)?

Comment: The simplest answer is *don't*... As Andrew is pointing out you're completely missing the point of using an ORM. EF and Linq will work all of that out for you. There is absolutely no reason to write SQL given your example.

Comment: I have multi parameter and I used a parameter here. If there is a better way please help me.

Comment: if you need multiple parms var qSearchByTypeText = database.tblNote.Where(note => note.fNumber == SNumber && note.SomeKindProp==anotherParam).ToList();

Comment: Thanks, How do I use the "contain" or "startswith"?

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass parameter like:

```
var qSearchByTypeText = database.tblNote.SqlQuery("select * From tblNote Where fNumber=@t0", new SqlParameter("@t0", SNumber)).ToList();
```

Comment: What "using" should I use?

Comment: using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

Comment: error: Additional information: No mapping exists from object type soft.SqlParameter to a known managed provider native type.

Comment: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for an EF6.0 "Using" statement to enclose an EF/ORM query that creates and returns a list of rows, here is what I would do:

```
var qSearchByTypeText = new List<Note>();  //where "Note" is a data structure that looks like a row of columns in "tblNote".

using (var myDbEntity = new [your 'Database First' Entity name]())
{
   //then your query
   qSearchByTypeText = (from n in myDBEntity.tblNotes where n.fNumber == SNumber select n).ToList();

}
```